# iCloudDrive - I can't to create the application folder in Files.app with a witch one Bundle Identifier

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, icloud, icloud-drive

I am trying to create application folder and upload an example `file.txt` to ***iCloud Drive***.

I'm using the next code:

```
@objc func testUploading() {

    let iCloudDocumentsURL = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Documents")

    //is iCloud working?
    if  iCloudDocumentsURL != nil {
        //Create the Directory if it doesn't exist
        if (!FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: iCloudDocumentsURL!.path, isDirectory: nil)) {
            //This gets skipped after initial run saying directory exists, but still don't see it on iCloud
            do {
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: iCloudDocumentsURL!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            } catch {
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("iCloud is NOT working!")
        return
    }

    //Set up directories
    let localDocumentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last! as NSURL

    //Add txt file to my local folder
    let myTextString = NSString(string: "HELLO WORLD")
    let myLocalFile = localDocumentsURL.appendingPathComponent("examplefile.txt")
    do {
        try myTextString.write(to: myLocalFile!, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    } catch {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    //If file exists on iCloud remove it
    var isDir:ObjCBool = false
    if (FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: iCloudDocumentsURL!.path, isDirectory: &isDir)) {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: iCloudDocumentsURL!)
        } catch {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    //copy from my local to iCloud
    do {
        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: localDocumentsURL as URL, to: iCloudDocumentsURL!)
    } catch {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

}
```

---

I have two targets in the project, each one for different environment, `Development` and `Production`, so the previous code runs well in my application when `development environment` is selected, the application can add app folder on `iCloud Drive`, running and compiling well.. but when I change to `production environment` the application also compile and run well but **can not add the application folder on** `iCloud-Drive`.

Next I show the capabilities of each environment:

> First picture is Production and second Development on ***Capabilities*** tab:

[image]

The unique difference between both targets is the way with `Capabilities` are setted, for `Production` target I am selecting check box ***Specify custom containers*** because `XCode` don't allow select ***Use default container***, on `Development environment` the selection is well to ***Use default container***.

> When ***Use default container*** checkbox is selected on `Production` appears next mistake:

[image]

This disparity I believe is caused because this application it's 4 years old, and I don't remember exactly for what, I created a custom `iCloud Container`, this one use the same name of application `Bundle Identifier` but lowercase.
**Apple** does not allow removing any container from `iCloud`, if it could, the error would be resolved.

- The following identifiers are the data that I believe cause the error

  > ***Bundle Identifier*** - com.reverse_domain ***.ControlHoras***
  >
  > ***iCloud Container ID*** - com.reverse_domain ***.controlhoras***

  `**The last path (Bold) the identifiers is the real case..`

For this reason and that `XCode` don't allow select option located on `Capabilities` > `iCLoud` > `Containers` > `Use default container`, I think I can not create the application folder in `iCloud Drive` in the `production environment`. Since the same project with the same code except the way of set *Capablilities*, one works well and the other does not.

---

Now that you are in context, I can asking my questions:

- Could someone explain to me why Apple let me add an iCloud Container that can generate this type conflict??
- Does anyone know any way to solve it?
- Does anyone know if It's possible to use iCloud Drive with a ***Specify custom container*** is selected (in my case I can't add folder on `iCloud-Drive`)?

I'm frustrated and spending a lot of time on this, I've tried everything and I do not know what way to go..

Thanks in advance!!

---

### UPDATE

I forgot it, these are `Entitlements` files:

***Production***

```
<dict>
<key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers</key>
<array>
    <string>iCloud.es.reverse_domain.controlhoras</string>
</array>
<key>com.apple.developer.icloud-services</key>
<array>
    <string>CloudDocuments</string>
</array>
<key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers</key>
<array>
    <string>iCloud.es.reverse_domain.controlhoras</string>
</array>
<key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
<string>$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
```

***Development***

```
<dict>
<key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers</key>
<array>
    <string>iCloud.$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
</array>
<key>com.apple.developer.icloud-services</key>
<array>
    <string>CloudDocuments</string>
</array>
<key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers</key>
<array>
    <string>iCloud.$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
</array>
<key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
<string>$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
```

---

> This is the aspect the iCloud Drive folders where only appears `development app`:

[image]

---

> **IMPORTANT NOTE:** I'm use `reverse_domain` in that question for my ID to remain anonymous, the rest of the identifiers are the originals.

---

### UPDATE 2

A few days ago I was trying use CloudKit, for a storing data on the cloud just before to starting use iCloud Drive but next of a time of development new features with iCloudKit it stopped working, and for that reason I start to develop that feature with iCloud Drive.

And I find this official post of Apple:

> CloudKit notifications won’t be delivered to your app if the notifications' shouldSendContentAvailable property is true and meanwhile your app is force quit. On iOS, users can force quit an app by double-tapping the home button and swiping it away from the multitasking UI.

It's possible what Apple banned mi `Bundle Identifier` for this reason since I was deploying with `shouldSendContentAvailable = true`?

If anyone has or had similar issue please let me know.